# meaning of this fiddler function

Tags: fiddlercore

Can any one explain to me the meaning of this function

```
AddHandler FiddlerApplication.BeforeResponse, AddressOf FiddlerBeforeResponseHandler
AddHandler FiddlerApplication.BeforeRequest, AddressOf FiddlerBeforeRequestHandler
AddHandler FiddlerApplication.AfterSessionComplete, AddressOf FiddlerAfterRequest
```

What the meaning of BeforeResponse, BeforeRequest and AfterSessionComplete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are events you can handle in FiddlerCore :

- `BeforeRequest` is raised by FiddlerCore just after he gets the request from the client (browser) and just before he sends the request to the server. You can modify client request from here.
- `BeforeResponse` is raised by FiddleCore just after he receive the response from the web server and just before he sends that response to the client. Unless the response was configured to stream (`oSession.bBufferResponse=false`), you can modify server response from here.
- `AfterSessionComplete` is raised after the final response was sent to the client.